# Google Analytics Custom Event Not Working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I've created a GA Goal (custom event) in my dashboard, as well as added the onClick function to the `<a></a>` I'm seeking to track.

However the click event isn't registering in my Google Analytics > Behaviors > Events > Overview dashboard.

Here is the 'onClick' function:

```
onclick="ga('send', {  hitType: 'event', eventCategory: 'Learn More Buttons', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Our Founder', eventValue: 10});"
```

Here is a screenshot of the Goal Details in my Google Analytics account:

[image]

I've also installed the Google Analytics debugger for Chrome and am not receiving an error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking under the real-time tab within the GA dashboard solved my problem.